# Losing information when saving an image as uint8

Tags: python, numpy, python-imaging-library

So I have an image, I'm just testing it with any random Google image, that I saved as "Picture.png". Now I want to normalize that image and save it as an .npy file, so I use the code:

```
from PIL import Image
import numpy as np

temp = Image.open("Picture.png")
image = np.asarray(temp)

def NormalizeData(data):
    return ((data - np.min(data)) / (np.max(data) - np.min(data)))

image = NormalizeData(image)
np.save("Picture.npy", image)
```

Then, I can retrieve the image with the code:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

image = np.load("Picture.npy")
plt.imshow(image)
plt.show()
```

The problem is that the .npy file is too big, so I added .astype('uint8') to the NormalizeData function, which saves tons of space. But now, when I try to plt.show() on the new uint8 .npy file, I get a white canvas.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you are normalizing the data to be between 0 and 1, then you are converting it to an integer. which will round all numbers to 0.

you should just multiply the numbers by 255 before using the `astype(np.uint8)` so numbers will be between 0 and 255 which is the correct range for unsigned 8 bit integers.